# Applying an adjustment matrix over each column of a timeseries-indexed DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm not familiar with applying matrix calculations and I'm getting nowhere fast in my attempts to apply the following complexity factors to *every* datapoint in my DataFrame (below values are all abof variable values). I've tried various combinations of `df.apply()`, `np.dot()` and `np.matrix()` but can't find a way (let alone a fast way!) to get the output I need.

## Matrix to be applied:

```
             0.6   0.3   0.1  (=1.0)
            |Low  |Med  |High
            ------------------
0.2   |Low  |1.1  |1.4  |2.0
0.4   |Med  |0.8  |1.0  |1.4
0.4   |High |0.6  |0.8  |1.1
(=1.0)
```

...so the calculation I'm trying to apply is as follows (if `datapoint` was 500, the adjusted result would be 454):

```
 (<datapoint> * (0.2 * 0.6 * 1.1) + (0.2 * 0.3 * 1.4) + (0.2 * 0.1 * 2.0))
+(<datapoint> * (0.4 * 0.6 * 0.8) + (0.4 * 0.3 * 1.0) + (0.4 * 0.1 * 1.4))
+(<datapoint> * (0.4 * 0.6 * 0.6) + (0.4 * 0.3 * 0.8) + (0.4 * 0.1 * 1.1))
```

## DataFrame for matrix to be applied over

The DataFrame for this matrix to be applied over has multi-level columns. Each column is an independent Series which runs across the DataFrame's timeseries index (empty datapoints filled with `NaN`).

The following code generates the test DataFrame I'm experimenting with:

```
element=[]
role=[]

#Generate the Series'
element1_part1= pd.Series(abs(np.random.randn(5)), index=pd.date_range('01-01-2018',periods=5,freq='D'))
element.append('Element 1')
role.append('Part1')
element1_part2= pd.Series(abs(np.random.randn(4)), index=pd.date_range('01-02-2018',periods=4,freq='D'))
element.append('Element 1')
role.append('Part2')
element2_part1= pd.Series(abs(np.random.randn(2)), index=pd.date_range('01-04-2018',periods=2,freq='D'))
element.append('Element 2')
role.append('Part1')
element2_part2= pd.Series(abs(np.random.randn(2)),  index=pd.date_range('01-02-2018',periods=2,freq='D'))
element.append('Element 2')
role.append('Part2')
element3 = pd.Series(abs(np.random.randn(4)), index=pd.date_range('01-02-2018',periods=4,freq='D'))
element.append('Element 3')
role.append('Only Part')


#Zip the multi-level columns to Tuples
arrays=[element,role]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

#Concatenate the Series' and define timeseries
elements=pd.concat([element1_part1, element1_part2, element2_part1, element2_part2, element3], axis=1)
dateseries=elements.index

elements.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Level-1', 'Level-2'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you want an elementwise-operation that updates the `elements` data frame with:

```
 (<datapoint> * [(0.2 * 0.6 * 1.1) + (0.2 * 0.3 * 1.4) + (0.2 * 0.1 * 2.0)])
+(<datapoint> * [(0.4 * 0.6 * 0.8) + (0.4 * 0.3 * 1.0) + (0.4 * 0.1 * 1.4)])
+(<datapoint> * [(0.4 * 0.6 * 0.6) + (0.4 * 0.3 * 0.8) + (0.4 * 0.1 * 1.1)])
```

For all `<datapoint>`, this operation has the form (with `x = <datapoint>`):

```
[x * (a + b + c)] + [x * (d + e + f)] + [x * (g + h + i)] 
= x * (a + ... + i)
= Cx # for some constant C
```

That means you just need to compute the scalar value `C`:

```
row_val = np.array([0.2, 0.4, 0.4])
col_val = np.array([0.6, 0.3, 0.1])

mat_val = np.matrix([[1.1, 1.4, 2.0], 
                     [0.8, 1.0, 1.4], 
                     [0.6, 0.8, 1.1]])

apply_mat = np.multiply(np.outer(row_val, col_val), mat_val)
apply_vec = np.sum(apply_mat, axis=1)
C = np.sum(apply_vec)
# 0.908
```

Or "by hand":

```
print(((0.2 * 0.6 * 1.1) + (0.2 * 0.3 * 1.4) + (0.2 * 0.1 * 2.0)) +
      ((0.4 * 0.6 * 0.8) + (0.4 * 0.3 * 1.0) + (0.4 * 0.1 * 1.4)) +
      ((0.4 * 0.6 * 0.6) + (0.4 * 0.3 * 0.8) + (0.4 * 0.1 * 1.1)))
# 0.908
```

This value for `C` matches your example datapoint and expected output:

```
0.908 * 500 = 454.0
```

Now you can use `mul()`:

```
elements.mul(C)
```

With your example data, this is the output:

```
Level-1    Element 1           Element 2           Element 3
Level-2        Part1     Part2     Part1     Part2 Only Part
2018-01-01  2.169116       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2018-01-02  0.620286  1.645149       NaN  1.173356  0.277663
2018-01-03  0.782959  1.677798       NaN  0.557048  1.220138
2018-01-04  0.206314  0.773896  0.629524       NaN  0.572183
2018-01-05  1.209667  0.542614  0.666525       NaN  0.579032
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. In case plugging in the numbers helps anyone: `apply_mat = np.multiply(np.outer([0.6,0.3,0.1], [0.2,0.4,0.4]), [1.1,1.4,2.0,0.8,1.0,1.4,0.6,0.8,1.1])`

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot to add in those variables.  Updating now.  (And you're welcome!)